# How can I scroll vertically in tvOS with SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, tvos, apple-tv

I don't know it's a SwiftUI specific problem but I can't scroll vertically in tvOS. It's just simple `List` that shows items.

```
var body: some View {
    List(items, id: \.self) { item in
         ItemView(item: item)
    }
}
```

There are 50+ items, but I can see about 10 of them.

I tried `option` + `arrow keys`, also tried with simulator's remote by holding `option` key. non of them worked. Is there anyone who encountered with it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On tvOS List content should be active, like buttons, and then you can use Remote, or arrows on keyboard for simulator to scroll through

(tested with Xcode 11.4)

```
var body: some View {
    List(items, id: \.self) { item in
         Button(action: {}) {
           ItemView(item: item)
         }
    }
}
```